# How to convert an image for a website menu button into CSS

Tags: css

I have images that I am currently using as a background for a button and when the button is clicked it changes so that it gives the impression it is being pressed, however I want to make the page more responsive so that when the browser window is resized it changes size too, and using this way doesn't seem to do it.

The images in question is below

[image: Button Image]

[image: Button Clicked Image]

Is there any way this can be done in CSS to give a similar result?

I have tried to do this, however, I have a new issue that when the browser window is smaller, the text doesn't shrink with the background, am I missing something?

```
#buttons {
    font-family:arial;
    text-align:center;
    color:#b5a642;          
}
#buttons ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
#buttons li a {
    width:10%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#7B4A18;
    color:#b5a642;
    padding:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 -30px 50px #603913 inset; 
    border: 5px solid #7B4A18;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #222, 0px 2px 4px #333;
}
#buttons li a:active {
    background-color:603913;
    box-shadow:0 -30px 50px #7B4A18 inset, 0 0 15px #222 inset;
    border:5px solid #603913;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #706729;
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfectly done by pure CSS. Can you try something? When you are stucked come here and ask a specific question. Guide: a border, a background, a text and 2 text shadows (white and black)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude do you have a guide of how to do it, as I'm not sure where to start?

Comment: Just first learn CSS. It's a really simple task. Any person that have minimal CSS knowledge can achieve this. References are thousands: MDN, CSS-tricks, codeacademy....

Comment: I can make the button for you, but there's not the spirit of stackoverflow (don't do others work). So you must try something first.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have edited my earlier post, I have tried but the text doesn't shrink when I make the browser smaller

Comment: @NickFallows You can adjust text sizing by using media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) in order to change CSS for your DOM accordingly to screen size for example.

In the following example I have tried to simplify your code to show the underlying concept.
The font size will change when you resize your browser window.

https://jsfiddle.net/9r2t6645/

```
<div id="buttons">
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
</ul>
</div>

#buttons {
    color:blue;   
    font-size: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  #buttons  {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#buttons li a {
   font-size:3vw;
}
```

Specifying widths and heights in vw (viewport width) / vh (viewport height) is similar to specifying in percentage of the screen (as compared to percentage of the container of the button)

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: @Coatless thanks, I'll try and keep that in mind. I think I was dashing to supper at the time.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#buttons {
    color:blue;   
    font-size: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  #buttons  {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To don't have an headache , try to use bootstrap framework and it will be 100% responsive.